# How to get entity with entityFieldQuery() that does not have a taxonomy term?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, entity, field

I have the following entityFieldQuery:

```
$tid = 1;

$articleQuery = new entityFieldQuery();

$nodes = $articleQuery
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
    ->fieldCondition('article_category', 'tid', array($tid), 'NOT IN')
    ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->range(0, 9)
    ->execute();
```

However it does not work. How can I fetch entities that do not have a particular taxonomy term?